# Vue.js как связать свойство с полем класса,

Tags: vue.js

Пишу приложение и приходится обрабатывать большое количество текстовых полей.

В html тестовое поле выглядит следующим образом:

```
<v-text-field
   v-model="field.model"
   :label=field.placeholderText
   outline
   clearable
 />
```

Блок script содержит массив items со свойствами для построения текстовых полей. Объект defaultConfig приходит с сервера.

```
export default {

    data() {
        return {

            defaultConfig: null,
            items: [
                {
                    header: 'Параметры генетического алгоритма',
                    fields: [
                        {
                             placeholderText: 'Семя генератора случ. чисел', 
                             type: 'text', 
                             model: '155557555'
                        },
                        {
                             placeholderText: 'Вероятность мутации',
                             type: 'text',
                             model: '2'
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    header: 'Настройки нишинга',
                    fields: [
                        {
                            placeholderText: 'Коэф-нт дополнительных генов (c1)',
                            type: 'text',
                            model: '2'
                        },
                        {
                            placeholderText: 'Коэф-нт непересекающихся генов (c2)',
                            type: 'text',
                            model: '2'
                        },
                        ]
                },

            ],
        }
    },
    methods:{
        getDefaultConfig(){
            this.$resource("/trainer/default-config").get().then(res => {
                if(res.ok){
                    res.json().then(data => {
                        this.defaultConfig = data
                    })
                }
            })
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.getDefaultConfig();
    }
}
```

**Предполагаю, что свойства являются ссылками, тогда КАК связать свойство с полем класса defaultConfig,ведь defaultConfig не доступен внутри items.**

То есть следующий код не работает

```
items: [
            {
                header: 'Параметры генетического алгоритма',
                fields: [
                    {
                         placeholderText: 'Семя генератора случ. чисел', 
                         type: 'text', 
                         model: defaultConfig.GENERATOR_SEED
                    },
                    {
                         placeholderText: 'Вероятность мутации',
                         type: 'text',
                         model: defaultConfig.MUTATION_PROBABILITY
                    },
                ]
            },
```

Структура defaultConfig:

```
    defaultConfig{
        "settings": {
            "POP_SIZE": "150",
            "GENERATOR_SEED": "1548235723799",
            "PROBABILITY_TOGGLELINK": "0.1",
            "PROBABILITY_MUTATION": "0.25",
            "PROBABILITY_WEIGHT_REPLACED": "0.0",
            "OUTPUT_ACTIVATIONFUNCTIONS": ";org.neat4j.neat.nn.core.functions.SigmoidFunction;",
            "ELE_SURVIVAL_COUNT": "0.1",
            "SPECIE_YOUTH_BOOST": "0.7",
            "KEEP_BEST_EVER": "true",
            "PROBABILITY_ADDNODE": "0.03",
            "MAX_PERTURB": "0.5",
            "INPUT_ACTIVATIONFUNCTIONS": "org.neat4j.neat.nn.core.functions.LinearFunction;;",
            "SURVIVAL_THRESHOLD": "0.2",
            "ELE_EVENT_TIME": "1000",
            "PROBABILITY_CROSSOVER": "0.5",
            "PROBABILITY_ADDLINK": "0.1",
            "SPECIE_OLD_PENALTY": "1.2",
            "COMPATABILITY_CHANGE": "0.1",
            "HIDDEN_ACTIVATIONFUNCTIONS": ";;org.neat4j.neat.nn.core.functions.TanhFunction",
            "FEATURE_SELECTION": "false",
            "ELE_EVENTS": "false",
            "SPECIE_YOUTH_THRESHOLD": "10",
            "RECURRENCY_ALLOWED": "false",
            "TERMINATION_VALUE": "0.00001",
            "PROBABILITY_MUTATEBIAS": "0.3",
            "COMPATABILITY_THRESHOLD": "0.5",
            "NATURAL_ORDER_STRATEGY": "true",
            "NUMBER_EPOCHS": "100",
            "EXCESS_COEFFICIENT": "1",
            "SPECIE_AGE_THRESHOLD": "80",
            "EXTRA_FEATURE_COUNT": "0",
            "MAX_BIAS_PERTURB": "0.1",
            "TERMINATION_VALUE_TOGGLE": "false",
            "WEIGHT_COEFFICIENT": "0.4",
            "SPECIE_FITNESS_MAX": "15",
            "PROBABILITY_NEWACTIVATIONFUNCTION": "0.1",
            "SPECIE_COUNT": "3",
            "DISJOINT_COEFFICIENT": "1"
          }
}
```

Comment: Возможно это Вам поможет - https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for

Comment: @РустамГимранов defaultConfig - это Map'a, которая приходит с сервера. Но если вам будет легче, вставлю кусок в вопрос.

Comment: @РустамГимранов HTML я привел обрезанным, он как раз таки находится в блоке for, так я обхожу items.

Comment: @Дмытрык settings - это как раз таки Map'a, которая содержится в родительском классе. Все остальные поля родительского класса не приходят с сервера, так как не несут нужной информации

Comment: Почему у Вас `field.model` в первом примере кода  равно 2, а во втором ссылается на конфиг?

Comment: @Дмытрык значение 2 - это затычка, так как не получается связать model с каким-либо полем из defaultConfig.

Вот меня и интересует эта задача. Как связать model с defaultConfig.GENERATOR_SEED, к примеру?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял: основная задача загрузить настройки, под каждую из которых будет динамически создано поле для редактирования. В примере ниже показана имитация загрузки, редактирования и сохранения значений `v-model` для динамически создаваемых полей ввода.

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // Определяем модель настроек.
    // Локальный объект.
    settings: {},

    // Массив для динамически
    // создаваемых полей ввода.
    items: [{
      header: 'Параметры генетического алгоритма',
      fields: [{
        placeholderText: 'Семя генератора случ. чисел',
        type: 'text',
        setting: 'POP_SIZE'
      }, {
        placeholderText: 'Вероятность мутации',
        type: 'text',
        setting: 'GENERATOR_SEED'
      }]
    }, {
      header: 'Настройки нишинга',
      fields: [{
        placeholderText: 'Коэф-нт дополнительных генов (c1)',
        type: 'text',
        setting: 'PROBABILITY_TOGGLELINK'
      }, {
        placeholderText: 'Коэф-нт непересекающихся генов (c2)',
        type: 'text',
        setting: 'PROBABILITY_MUTATION'
      }]
    }]
  },

  async mounted() {
    this.settings = await this.fetchData()
  },

  methods: {
    // В примере имитируем, но вы сами решите
    // как правильнее для вас загружать данные.
    fetchData() {
      return {
        "POP_SIZE": "150",
        "GENERATOR_SEED": "1548235723799",
        "PROBABILITY_TOGGLELINK": "0.1",
        "PROBABILITY_MUTATION": "0.25"
      }
    },
    save() {
      alert('Сохранили куда надо и как надо локальное свойство settings.')
      // console.log(this.settings)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <form @submit.prevent="save">
    <div class="" v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <h3>{{ item.header }}</h3>
      <div class="" v-for="field in item.fields">
        <v-text-field v-model="settings[field.setting]" :label="field.placeholderText" outline clearable />
      </div>
    </div>

    <v-btn type="submit">Сохранить</v-btn>
  </form>
  <pre>{{ settings }}</pre>
</div>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ подключить на шаблон директиву `v-if` с флагом, который станет в значение 
`true`, когда прийдет ответ сервера. А дальше такой код

```
<div v-for="(item, itemIndex) in items" :key="itemIndex">
    <v-text-field 
       v-for="(field, fieldIndex) in item.fields" :key="fieldIndex"
       v-model="defaultConfig.setthigs[field.model]"
       :label=field.placeholderText
       outline
       clearable
     />
 </div>
```

Comment: c HTML и блоком for у меня проблем нет. У меня проблемы с тем, чтобы field.model имел связь с defaultConfig.value. Это для того чтобы при изменении значения в текстовом поле, сразу же менялось значение в объекте класса defaultConfig, с ним связанное

Comment: ну так напишите об этом внятно в вопросе и приведите код defaultConfig, который Вы получаете с сервера

Comment: обновил ответ с учетом новых данных

Comment: defaultConfig.setthigs[field.model] - вот этой строчки я не понял. field.model - это свойство, которое должно производить двунаправленную связку. То есть field.model - это не индекс в массиве.

Comment: Что, в данном случае, Вы понимаете под "двунаправленной связью"? Какого эффекта Вы хотите достичь?

Comment: field.model должно быть изменяемо посредством ввода значений в текстовое поле и в тоже время, field.model должно изменять значение в defaultConfig.GENERATOR_SEED, к примеру

Comment: Сдается, мне, Вы как-то не так решаете ту основную заддачу, которая перед Вами стоит.... Даже, если Вам потом необходимо будет отправить введенные данные обратно не сервер, то даже в таком случае связь, которую Вы хотите настроить - не нужна

Comment: Я тоже чувствую, что от item.model можно избавится. Но я не знаю как иначе связать и item и defaultConfig и текстовое поле воедино, если учесть, что все построение элементов происходит в цикле, аналогично вашему ответу.